# Fetch top terms with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, rsolr

solr have a admin console like

```
http://localhost:8982/solr/admin/schema.jsp
```

which provides some schema fields data like top terms and freq for specific field.

I am using sunspot, and how to query data like this?
like TOP 10 terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure for Sunspot but check for Solr [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) which will allow you to retrieve the top terms with the frequency from a field.

Answer (score 0):

while, my current solution is using Luke query some XML data and parse it by hand
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler

for anyone who is interesting.